# VS2008 & Local IIS Web Server - all components installed, doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis, iis-7, iis-6

In VS2008, when checking the local server option in the web tab in the project window, the error message reads:

---

To access local IIS Web sites, you must install the following IIS components:

IIS 6 Metabase and IIS 6 Configuration Compatibilty
ASP.NET
Windows Authentication

In addition you must run Visual Studio in the context of an administrator account

---

The iis6 metabase, windows authentication and asp.net features are already installed.  Also running VS as administrator.  Using iis7, vs2008 32bit, vista ultimate 64 bit.

I tried installing the other iis6 features (scripts, console) and <strike>got an error</strike> got a useless message that told me nothing, but eventually found out that Vista doesn't support iis6.

Right now, am trying to uninstall the iis6 metabase and install it again.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: "doesn't work"...... would love to help you more but that is not very useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem - had to start the web management service.

The Web Management Service enables remote and delegated management capabilities for administrators to manage for the Web server, sites and applications present on this machine.

Got help from here: http://forums.iis.net/t/1159087.aspx